# Google Analytics Schema

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-analytics-api

What is the field that I need to query in order to get the number of Users in BigQuery from the GA Schema?

I cannot find it in the schema reference link provided by BigQuery: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en

I can generate the New Users metric but not the Users metric

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vinay,

Since you don't want New Users but rather need to count returning users as well, how that would be different from counting sessions for the time period you are interested in?

Thanks,
Ilya

Comment: sessions and users are not the same thing. i am just looking for total users to monitor growth and share.

Comment: Vinay, 

Counting the distinct values of fullVisitorId is probably what you need: `COUNT (DISTINCT(fullVisitorId)) as total_users`

Please keep in mind that count() results are approximate for results greater than 1000 unless you specify a greater threshold number as a second parameter or use EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT.